# ETL Oracle to Cassandra

Tags: oracle, cassandra, etl, data-migration, bulk

We had some users which their info. was stored in Oracle db. the tables include some Joins, too.

Now, I want to build a new project, using Cassandra which will use the information of previews users, too.

The data modeling is using Cassandra principles. But the question is that:
How I can **move or migrate the needed hole heavy data from Oracle to new non-relational database**? (what steps)

Answer (score 1):

Usually, you should use the "[Cassandra Bulk Loader](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/using-the-cassandra-bulk-loader-updated)" tool. And this link talks many considerations about "[MySQL to Cassandra Migrations](http://www.planetcassandra.org/mysql-to-cassandra-migration/)", which should be similar to migrating from Oracle.